# NTLDR Technical Info

Tags: windows, bootloader

I'm trying to figure out as much as I can about how `NTLDR` works. My biggest question is the following:

1) What kind of executable format does `NTLDR` use?

I'm also curious about the following, but once I know the file format I bet these two will be easy to figure out.

2) Where in memory should `NTLDR` be loaded?

3) What is the entry point for `NTLDR`?

Comment: NTLDR is a flat binary that is designed to start in 16-bit real mode. The bootloader can load it anywhere (it is generally written to be relocatable) but since it starts executing in real mode it will be limited to the first 1mb of RAM. Since it is a simple flat binary the entry point will be the first byte of NTLDR. NTLDR is generally called via a FAR JMP.